# RegEx for certain characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I am trying to use regex to strip out all unwanted characters on string like spaces " ", dots ".",  dashes "-", and "The"

Like "The Dark-Knight Rises."
And Output "DarkKnightRises"

This is only far as i got

```
.replaceAll("\\s+", "")
```

I'm a complete noob,

Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
String str = "The Dark-Knight Rises.";
String repl = str.replaceAll("(?i)[ .-]+|\\bthe\\b", "");
//=> DarkKnightRises
```

Comment: Glad it worked out, please consider making this as accepted now.